# Will aws elb address change over time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have created a load balancer pointing at my api instances. I got an automatically generated url which looks something like this:
xxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxx.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com
I want to connect it to my own domain name via cname, but before doing this, I wanted to make sure that the url will always stay the same, unless I delete the lb of course. Thanks for the kind help.

Answer (score 2):

This hostname is unique to your load balancer and will remain the same as long as your load balancer is running. This means that you can safely create a CNAME record that points to the ELB DNS name without worrying about the URL changing unexpectedly.

However, it's important to note that if you delete and recreate your load balancer, you will be given a new ELB DNS name. If you're planning on creating a CNAME record that points to your ELB DNS name, you should make sure that you're okay with the possibility of having to update your DNS record in the future if you need to replace your load balancer.

Comment: Adding onto the is reply. Never use the IP addresses that the hostname resolves to. They WILL change over time and you won't have any warning of the change. Use a CNAME or an alias (if you are using Route53) only.